# Fubini's Thm used to evaluate Integrand

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_y^1 sin\frac{y}{x}dx\right) dy$$ I was working on some new material and came across this. Honestly, I feel as though this is just going over my head and feel a bit dumb for not being able to grasp the concept. I can post the theorem in hopes that it may help. Any suggestions?

Funbini: Let $f \in H_I(\mathbb{R}^d), i_1... i_d$ a permutation of (1,...,d), 1$\leq c \leq d.$ For $(x^{i_{c+1}},...,x^{i_{d}})$ let $$F(x^{i_{c+1}},...,x^{i_{d}}) :=\int_{\mathbb{R}^c}f(\xi,x^{i_{c+1}},...,x^{i_d})  with  \xi = (x^{i_1},...,x^{i_c}).$$ Then $$\int_\mathbb{{R}^d}f(x)dx = \int_\mathbb{{R}^{d-c}}F(\eta)d\eta , \eta=(x^{i_{c+1}},...,x^{i_d})$$Here is what I have gotten so far, but I am unsure where to go from here. Please let me know if i've missed a step or am going in the wrong direction.

$I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^x \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)dydx$, and let $u = \dfrac{y}{x} \implies du = \dfrac{dy}{x}, \displaystyle \int_{0}^x \sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)dy = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 xu\sin(u) du$

Answer (score 0):

Using Fubini's theorem,
$$\int_0^1\int_y^1\sin\frac{y}{x}dxdy=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^x\sin\frac{y}{x}dy\right)dx=\left(\star\right)$$
Note that in the inner integral, $x$ is a constant, so
$$\int_0^x\sin\frac{y}{x}dy=\left(-x\cos\frac{y}{x}\right|_0^x=-x\cos 1+x\cos 0=x\left(1-\cos 1\right)$$
Therefore,
$$\left(\star\right)=\int_0^1x\left(1-\cos 1\right)dx=\left(\frac{1-\cos 1}{2}x^2\right|_0^1=\frac{1-\cos 1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you want to apply Fubini's Theorem. (You're on the right track, but I think you messed up your substitution.) So, since an antiderivative of $\sin(cy)$ with respect to $y$ is $-\dfrac1c\cos(cy)$, we have
$$I = \int_0^1\int_0^x \sin\left(\frac yx\right)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1 \left[-x\cos\left(\frac yx\right)\right]_0^x\,dx = \dots$$